# What do special characters stand for in echo {A..z}

Tags: echo, shell-builtin

I know we can print a sequence of letters of the Alphabet using `echo` command and experimented it a little by doing this.

Lowercase letter Sequence

```
$ echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Uppercase letter Sequence

```
$ echo {A..Z}
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
```

Uppercase and Lowercase letter Sequence

```
$ echo {A..z}
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [  ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Now this is the part that I don't get. See the `special charcaters` from Z to a. Here's a better view.

```
$ echo {a..Z}
a ` _ ^ ]  [ Z
```

I want to know

1. How these special characters came here in between Uppercase and lowercase letters ?
2. What does these special character sequence mean ?
3. Also, How do I only print this sequence in-between ?

Answer (score 4):

`{A..z}` expands according to the character encoding of your current locale, which most likely is ASCII or something close to it. If you run `man ascii` (in case you have this on your system) or have a look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) you see these additional characters in-between `Z` and `a` (the same you get when running `echo {Z..a}` actually).

To get just upper/lowercase characters use

```
echo {A..Z} {a..z}
```

To get just those in-between you may use

```
typeset -a foo=($(echo {Z..a}))
echo ${foo[@]:1:((${#foo[@]} - 2))}
```

which creates an array first *including* the two characters just outside the boundary and then accesses all array elements *besides* the boundary characters.

PS: Figuring out why `typeset -a foo=({Z..a})` doesn't work is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: How to print only this sequence through echo -  `   _   ^   ]    [   that is inbetween uppercase and lowercase letters ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus ``echo '` _ ^ ]  ['``

Comment: You'll notice backslash is missing in there (suggesting you've tried that in `bash` instead of `zsh`) and is been replaced with an empty argument. And if you replace `{A..z}` with `{A..z}x` you get an error about an unclosed `\`` in `bash`. That's another side effect of brace expansion being done very early in bash contrary to other shells.

Comment: `typeset -a foo=({Z..a})` seems to work on Bash 4.3/4.4 (except for the backslash and backtick)

Comment: Actually, foo is missing the backslash (ASCII 1C). Only this code seems to actually set all the characters in between ASCII Z and ASCII a: `declare foo=('Z' '[' '\' ']' '^' '_' '`' 'a'); declare -p foo`.